# Is my company doing this right, sharing data between exes?

Tags: c++, mfc

First off, my company is into power grid, not IT, so software is kinda a secondary role here.

I work on a power system simulation software, very old code base in C++ with MFC, like 15 years old. What we do is take large amounts of data, ~100,000 floating point values then format and write to a text file (most of the code actually uses the C FILE structure to do this). Then, it's read by a separate engine exe which computes the electrical algorithm (Electrical algorithms are mostly numeric solutions of system of diffn equations) and then writes back huge amount of data to another text file, which we read and update the UI.

My question is, is this how it should be done? It there a way to skip writing into the text file and directly pass the data to the exes?

exes are called using CreateProcess() MFC function.

EDIT::
Sorry, site won't let me comment.

@Vlad Feinstein Well, yes, it's like a Ladder. A thing called load flow solves power flow through the lines, which in turn will be used to find stability of the systems, which in turn for overvoltage ect. It's huge, the UI is million+ lines of code, engine exes another million maybe.

Doesn't MFC already implement IPC using Dynamic Data Exchange? I can pass strings to another process's PreTranslateMessage() func. A scaled up version of that?

Comment: Very thoughful. I would prefer to keep the logic of processing data in a library. (Not much different from exe)

Comment: If it works, why fix it?

Comment: How is writing to a text file not direct? Are you under the misconception that the data is actually being written to disk and then back out again?

Comment: Well you could always use IPC, pipes or shared memory or whatever, or even connect the standard output of process 1 to standard input of process 2.

Comment: As @DavidSchwartz said, the data may not be physically written to disk at that point. However, it will most certainly get formatted as text ant then parsed back into binaries; that might take some significant time. As was suggested above, you can convert your second exe into a library; then it will have direct access to your 100,000 floats without the need to copy it anywhere. So the question is: is your second exe used by any other applications?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a thing as "should be done as ..." there are multiple methods to do IPC and while the method you describe might not be the fastest, it is a viable solution nevertheless. If the performance doesn't bother you in this particular case you should not bother with modifying it. It is exactly the case where the phrase *"if it ain't broke, don't fix it"* applies.

Probably, you would not want to make any *new* IPC in the application that way, though.